# SQL Symmetric Key Encryption Alternative

Tags: sql-server, failover, encryption-symmetric

I am looking for an alternative to symmetric key encryption to savely store sensitive data in a Microsoft SQL database. The reason for this is a few days ago I had an error during the night (at 3 am) where the database responded my status call, which is used for health checks of the backend, with an error

> A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

(The call I am using for health check is only calling my rest api - going through the web service to the database, does a *select count(*) from Member* and returns the count.)

After that error every api call which used sensitive data from the database returned

> Please create a master key in the database or open the master key in the session before performing this operation.

My monitor service said that the backend was up again after 2 minutes automatically but the master key was not working anymore. I fixed it with the following command

`open master key decryption by password = 'password'
alter master key add encryption by service master key`

the morning after but in the meantime the backend was not working correctly. So the failover didn't really did its job (because I had to do something manually to get everything working again).

So I am trying to achieve to store sensitive data easily in the database (must be able to decrypt it again) and to have a working failover without doing anything manually too.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2):

What i think I'm reading is that you have some sort of HA technology in play (e.g. availability groups). If that's the case, care needs to be taken to ensure that both sides of the topology can open the database master key.

Fortunately, it's fairly easy to do that. You can backup and restore service master keys (SMK). So, you'll backup the SMK from the secondary node and restore it to the primary node. SQL Server will decrypt anything currently encrypted with the old key and re-encrypt with the new.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can this be done by the sql server automatically if db server A is replaced by db server B in case of a critical error? I don't want to to this manually at 3 am in the morning - failover should work automatically without any human interaction. (p.s.: I am using a multi-az database from aws)

Comment: This is something that you'd do well in advance of the failover and would allow the failover to work without you having to manually open the DMK. In short: yes! 

Comment: Sure, but its not really clear to me how I can achieve this. AWS mirrors the db to a second db in another availability zone and replaces the primary db with the mirror db automatically in case of a critical error. So AWS does the job for me. I would have to check everytime when trying to use the SMK if its possible and if not i have to restore it?

Comment: Ooh… I don't have any personal experience with Amazon RDS. From what I remember though, they use database mirroring on the back end to provide HA. Do you have access to the mirroring secondary server? If so, you'd copy the SMK from there and restore it to your primary. I don't know how much control they give you at the server level though (being a managed service).

Comment: I found out that this is not possible: https://serverfault.com/questions/740016/can-i-access-the-failover-server-on-aws-rds

Comment: That comment says that the *database* isn't available for reading. What you're looking for, however, is a server-level object. Just like you'd expect logins to work seamlessly across an HA failover, so to would I expect this to work. If nothing else, this might be something that you can take up with Amazon support as "this should work".